# Pop out symbol signifying a link

Tags: symbols

How can I create the pop out symbol in latex?

[image]

Signifies that something is a link.

I used a latex symbol finder but it tells me the closest match is the male gender symbol, which I guess is pretty similar but not entirely.

Hoping there is just a command for this so that I don't have to draw it myself.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The package `fontawesome5` provides to get your simbol with the command `\faExternalLink*`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontawesome5}
\begin{document}
\faExternalLink*
\end{document}
```

Here there is the output:

[image]